# what does it mean for `new` to be no-throw guaranteed when bad_alloc is not thrown

Tags: c++, std

From the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) of `new`:

> The first version (1) throws bad_alloc if it fails to allocate
>   storage. Otherwise, it throws no exceptions (no-throw guarantee).

To me, this should mean that this code

```
#include <new>

struct A{
    A(){
        throw 0;
    }  
};

int main(){
    try{
        A* a = new A;
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc&){}
}
```

is perfectly fine. However, when compiling it with gcc (see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=5843de05786c3ed6af0dde1df83d731e-37e310707bc41fe992acad9d9b03bc56)), the program terminates after throwing an `int`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's the documentation of `operator new`, which is not the same as the `new` expression. A `new` expression calls `operator new` to obtain memory *and then* calls the constructor requested on that memory. `operator new` does not throw anything other than `std::bad_alloc`, but the later call to the constructor can throw whatever the user code wants.

Compare [`new` expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) with [`operator new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new).

Answer (score 4):

The expression `new A` normally does two things:

1. Call `operator new` to get some storage.
2. Call a constructor of `A` to create an `A` object within that storage.

The quote you pasted only describes the behavior of the function `::operator new(std::size_t)`.  Here step 2 throws an `int` after `operator new` has already succeeded and exited.

(In this example, C++ does make sure the allocated memory is passed to `operator delete` before you get to any `catch` handler.)

Answer (score 2):

The keyword`new` is no-throw guarenteed, not the class you're allocating (`A`). You've explicitly defined the constructor for `A` as throwing an exception; when an `A` is allocated, `A` throws the exception, not `new`.